# Change TotalRowCount in Listview

Tags: asp.net, listviewitem, datapager

I  want to manipulate Total Row count of the listview i am not able to set the value in `OnTotalRowCountAvailable` Event because in this event `TotalRowCount` is Read Only i cant set any new value .As per my knowledge DataPager using Total Row Count to display it.

Here I am trying to control the page display of `DataPager`. Is any one know how to set new value on `TotalRowCount`, Or any `Event` where i can change this value.

Thank you Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You could add more items to your listview I suppose -
maybe blank lines even if you don't want text  :)

```
Listview.value "\n"
```

I'm not 100% that it will do the trick though, since I'm not completely sure what you want